# How to run content script only on the active tab in a ReactJS Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension using ReactJS that includes a sidebar for users to take notes and access other features. However, I'm encountering an issue where some actions are triggered on inactive tabs. I want to ensure that the content script only runs on the active tab to avoid any confusion for users.

I'm wondering if anyone has experience with this and could suggest the best way to approach it? If possible, I would appreciate any code examples or tutorials that could help me achieve this.

Thank you for your time and any help you can provide.

ps. I try to run `chrome.tabs.query` in the content script file but as the documentation said

> The Tabs API can be used by the service worker and extension pages, but not content scripts.

Comment: Content script declared in manifest.json runs in all tabs with the matching URL. How do you declare/load your content script?

Comment: @wOxxOm here is my content_script in manifest:
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "runAt": "document_end",
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "match_about_blank": false,
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ]

Comment: Yeah, it'll run in all tabs. You can check document.hasFocus() and `visibilitychange` event.